# Page Not Found on home network server (Ubuntu, PHP Apache, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, php, ubuntu

I have  just set up a server on my home network to allow testing of a development website from several computers. Ubuntu and the usual programs (Apache, PHP, MySQL) are also installed.

The website, although still not a production site, is also up on a web host and all works well there. I uploaded a copy of all the Drupal (Ver 7) files to the new server as well as the database.

Since it's a home based server, the IP of the site is 192.168.1.8. If I enter the www.example.com in the URL, my browser points to the copy of the site on the server of the hosting company.

If I enter 192.168.1.8, I am taken to the front page of the site on my home server. Everything there displays well. I do not want this new server to be accessible to the public yet.

However if I click, say, on the "request new password" link of the User Login block of the front page, I get a "Not Found - The requested URL/user/password was not found on this server" message and the URL reads "192.168.1.8/user/password"

Ditto with the create new account page and all pages directly accessible to unregistered users such as the About Us page or the Terms of Service Page.

If I try to log into my account (from the front page login block) I am not taken anywhere and remain on the front page.

Now, I do plan to develop this home server to make it accessible from the web in the future but I know I will need a fixed IP address and a DNS that will point to it.

In the mean time, however, how can I have the site work on this new server? It's only for testing purposes at the moment so what shows in the URL is unimportant.

As far as I could see, all folders have a permission of 755.

Any thought or suggestion to make this work?

Thank you. :)

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site.  Perhaps it should be moved to http://serverfault.com or perhaps http://superuser.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue in a Drupal setup. Please see http://superuser.com/ or possibly http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ as better resources (check their help section). Do not post this on Server Fault, they don't take questions for home servers.

Comment: @Mat That's an interesting standard for serverfault to have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Gerald Schneider - This is the correct answer. It seems like a missing or invalid .htaccess file.

[You may try this website (Mod_rewrite generator)](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/). I use it and it works.

Edit: Why the downvote? The answer is more than likely correct and I have provided a link for a tool to create a .htaccess.

Comment: Sorry about the downvote, I got one too :) It turns out that this is not a Drupal issue as wrongly alleged but an Apache module that is missing on the server (mod_rewrite Apache module) that coordinates clean urls and the .htaccess file. So your answer (as well as Gerald's) was correct. Do not take offense at the downvote as it only shows ignorance and immaturity on the part of its author, whomever he may be.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a missing `.htaccess` file. Check if you copied it over, some FTP clients don't show these hidden files by default.